# I don't get notification for achievements in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

I don't find a notification when I somehow earn or lost reputation points. But, in the web version I get notified by +2 or +10.

- App version: 1.0.95
- Device manufacturer: Symphony
- Device model: V75

  - OS version: 6.0 (eng.android.1482838674)

Comment: Don't think this is a bug, seems like intended behaviour, you get a notification for comments or answers. Seems a good thing to leave out too, who would want their phone going off for every small rep ajustment?

Comment: It's may my folt that I haven't trying to say status bar notification rather in app notification.

Answer (score 2):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You're only supposed to receive notifications of (red) inbox notifications, not (green) achievement notifications.